# Default Server 20.04 install

Tags: usb, password

I think I am going mad. I followed all paths to the same result, Googled my head off, but always end up with the same; it should work but it doens't ...
I am using some former (hardened linux based) firewall appliances that are able to run Ubuntu perfectly for testing (or even production) purposes; SSD, 2 or 4 GB RAM, USB, enough Ethernet, RJ45 serial console etc. But indeed .. headless (no mouse and display) so depending on either SSH or otherwise remote connectivity.
Downloaded Ubuntu 20.04 server ISO, put it onto an 32GB USB drive with Rufus, switched on the appliance, checked with serial putty, booted and via connected once Ubuntu was loaded and prompted to login.
The default should be ubuntu/ubuntu but I cannot get this working. All seems well, I tried other tools, ending with the same, so where did go wrong? I cannot get access to any command, so editing anything is useless. I tried different systems with all the same result, so the error seems ... me :-(.
Has anyone any suggestion to pull me out of this misery?

everything is much appreciated.

Comment: Why should the SSH login be `ubuntu` & `ubuntu`? Have you preconfigured the installation in some manner?

Comment: How did you install the Ubuntu server from the USB to the SSD without any monitor and keyboard? Did you use a different computer? Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1319337/edit) and add all the new information everyone asks in the comments **in your question**.

Comment: I used all defaults as most people follow that. Ubuntu/ubuntu is mentioned as default u/pw

Comment: as @user68186 said, the default iso version of ubuntu server needs monitor to install. Consider that you didn't even set the username and password which should be set at the installation process. So connect your server to a monitor and install the ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

Let's take a look at the Ubuntu Server Installer help screen for SSH:

[image]

- You can see that the Help menu has an entry: **Help on SSH access**
- That screen (shown above) has the login name (installer) and randomly-generated password that you need.

In other words, it's not possible to do a headless install the way you are trying to do it. You must have a monitor/keyboard in order to learn the installer's SSH password.

However, the Ubuntu Server installer uses cloud-init. It's not trivial, and there is a learning curve, but you CAN make all kinds of changes (like your own login and ssh key) to the installed defaults using cloud-init. Cloud-init is powerful and complex; it's not for beginners. See [this documentation](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/datasources/nocloud.html) for one example of how to use NoCloud to package a custom cloud-init file into a format that the installer will look for. Then you can do headless server installs.

- Note for future readers. There is a transition in progress from Preseed/d-i to cloud-init. Ubuntu 20.04 Desktop and Server use completely different installers. Tips for one generally won't work on the other:  Server cannot use Preseed d-i statements, and Desktop cannot use Cloud-init.

  Older 18.04 both use Preseed, and the yet-to-be-built 22.04 it is possible that both might use cloud-init instead.

  Know which installer you are using, know which features are compatible with it, and recognize that some instructions you find might be for the other.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu Server 20.04 installer has a new feature to *complete* an installation over SSH.

But it is not for a headless installation. You boot the installer, go to Help menu using keyboard and monitor and get random-generated SSH credentials from here. Never worked for me, though (SSH session has been laggy and hanged up at some point).

See [Using the server installer](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/install/general):

> **Connecting to the installer over SSH**
>
> If the only available terminal is
> very basic, an alternative is to connect via SSH. If the network is up
> by the time the installer starts, instructions are offered on the
> initial screen in basic mode. Otherwise, instructions are available
> from the help menu once networking is configured.
>
> In addition, connecting via SSH is assumed to be capable of displaying
> all unicode characters, enabling more translations to be used than can
> be displayed on a virtual terminal.
>
> **Help menu**
>
> The help menu is always in the top right of the screen. It
> contains help, both general and for the currently displayed screen,
> and some general actions.